# Postman requests are getting faster and faster

Tags: spring, performance, caching, postman, quarkus

Every postman requests spent less and less time

[image]

This is the first request

[image]

And this is second.

Why does it work like this? I saw this when I was writing spring application and now the same with quarkus.

Comment: First request will often invoke code for the first time which can trigger class loading, ioc wiring, machine native code caching, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to running your JSP pages when running a Spring application, at the first time, everything is getting compiled, built, rendered, and presented, and many other operations, but if you hit refresh for that JSP page again, it will happen much faster because it does not compile, build and rendered every time, it is just being present.

This is just a very simple example to get an idea, you are probably not using JSP pages, but the concept is still the same.

Basically, first requests in theory do like 10 tasks, but after everything is done, the number of tasks is much lower, hence the speed.